# What NM_CONTROLLED variable does in centos/RHEL?

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, linux-networking

I have found that we can enable or disable network manager using NM_CONTROLLED flag in ifcfg-interface file.

What does this flag do? Can anyone explain correctly?

Answer (score 6):

The variable `NM_CONTROLLED` determines if the interface will be managed via NetworkManager (`yes`) or via the legacy network scripts (`no`).

For a quick example, read [here](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/centos-rhel-7-how-to-disable-networkmanager/amp/)